# A list of the namespaces created by import statements

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I've a script tag (`type="module"`), which is dynamically populated with `import` statements by PHP based on some parameters. The populating process is controlled by the authorization system of the site, and it can drop some `import`s from the script, depending on the rights of the current user.

An example of the final rendered script tag on a page:

```
<script type="module">
    import ui from 'path_to_ui_module';
    import read from 'path_to_read_module';
    import edit from 'path_to_edit_module';     // Could be omitted by the authorization
    import create from 'path_to_create_module'; // Could be omitted by the authorization
    import delete from 'path_to_delete_module'; // Could be omitted by the authorization
    ui.init();
</script>
```

All the imports are guaranteed to be objects only.

Now, the problem lies in `ui.init` method, where I want to assign some references of some properties of the loaded modules (and their submodules) to a property in `ui`, but I don't know, which modules are actually loaded, because the authorization system may have dropped some of the modules from the script. For example, all the loaded modules have a `cmd` object containing various methods, and I'd like to assign a reference to those methods to `ui.cmd` object. How can I iterate through all the namespaces of the imported modules, including the possible submodules imported by the modules loaded in the script?

Currently I've modified the authorization system to create the `ui.init` call, which passes the references of the really loaded modules to `ui.init` method, but the submodules are naturally not included.

`ui.init({modules: {read: read, edit: edit, create: create, delete: delete});`

(The modules dropped by the authorization system are not included in `modules` object.)

With the passed `modules` object, a simplified `ui.init` method looks like this ("main module" in the comments is `ui`, "submodule" refers to the modules passed via the arguments):

```
init (options) {
    for (const module in options.modules) {
        this[module] = options.modules[module];    // Add submodule reference to the main object
        this[module].main = this;                  // Add main module reference to submodule
        Object.assign(this.cmd, this[module].cmd); // Assign the cmd methods of the submodule to the main module's cmd object
        this[module].init();                       // Initialize the submodule
    }
}
```

Reformed question: Is there a native "list" of all imported modules, including the submodules the imported modules have imported, available, that I can use instead of `options.modules` in the `for .. in` loop? Or alternatively, is there a way for the submodules to somehow "expose" themselves after they've been loaded, so that they can create a list of the loaded modules?

Comment: For now, I ended up to maintain a list object of the loaded submodules in the local code of all the imported modules. `init` method of the imported module checks whether the list exists, and assigns the list as a property to the imported object. `init` method of the main module checks the list of the submodule, and recursively calls itself passing the list as the argument. A flaw in this solution is, that the main module itself can't contain the list. Hence I'm still intrested in an answer providing a list of all the loaded modules, preferrably without adding any code to the submodules.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using dynamic imports:
*(I am assuming that your PHP script can dynamically generate the `.then` callback)*

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      Promise
        .all
          ( [ import('./node_modules/the-answer/dist/the-answer.es.js')
            , import('./node_modules/the-answer/dist/the-answer.es.js')
            , import('./node_modules/the-answer/dist/the-answer.es.js')
            ]
          )
        .then(([{default: answer1}, {default: answer2}, {default: answer3}]) => {
          // You now know all the modules that have loaded 
          console.log(answer1, answer2, answer3);
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Because the dynamic form of `import` returns a promise, you can wait for all of them to resolve and have access to them.

The `the-answer` module is [literally](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/the-answer/blob/master/src/index.js) this:

```js
export default 42;
```

Which is why I need to destructure each module in the `.then()` method, e.g.

```js
.then(([{default: answer1}]) => alert(answer1))
```

Comment: Yes, I can modify the PHP script to generate dynamic imports. But somehow I can't see how all the submodules imported by the known modules can be referred with your solution. I'll try to implement this in my code, but it'll take several hours before I can give any further feedback (it's a very late night here).

Comment: This code can replace the static imports, but it can only provide the same functionality as my code in the question, i.e. it can't detect the submodules loaded by the imported modules. Unfortunately I can't use the answer, but this could be very useful to future readers.